# How to break a line in between two textViews when both the textViews are having different styles programatically

Tags: android, textview

I am building a cart view for an e-commerce app and I want to build a View in which my product name should be bold and of bigger text size and under that a small description of the product which is of smaller text size should be there but I am facing the problem to break a line in between these two textViews. My code is something like this

```
for (int j=0;j< productsize;j++){
            String pName = ct.getProducts(j).getProductName();
            int pPrice = ct.getProducts(j).getProductPrice();
            String desc = ct.getProducts(j).getProductDesc();
            LinearLayout la = new LinearLayout(this);
            la.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(" " + pName + " ");//first textView
            tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 22F);
            la.addView(tv);

            TextView des = new TextView(this);//second textView
            des.setText("" + desc + "");

            la.addView(des);


 final Button btn1 = new Button(this);
            btn1.setId(j+1);
            btn1.setText("Add to Cart");
            btn1.setLayoutParams(params);
            final int index = j;
            btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.i("TAG", "index:"+index);
                    ModelProducts productsObject = ct.getProducts(index);
                    if(!ct.getCart().CheckProductInCart(productsObject)){
                        btn1.setText("Item Added");
                        ct.getCart().setProducts(productsObject);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New CartSize:" +ct.getCart().getCartsize(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Products"+(index+1)+"Already Added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            la.addView(btn1);
            layout.addView(la);
        }
```

Can anyone help me with this please thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
la.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

to this:

```
la.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

**Updated:**

If you want the two `TextViews` aligned vertically and the `Button` horizontally aligned, then you need to use a `RelativeLayout` or two `LinearLayouts`.

Using two `LinearLayouts` you may try to form the structure like this:

```
<LinearLayout with horizontal orientation....
.....
    <LinearLayout with vertical orientation....
    ...
        <TextView.....
        <TextView .....
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button .....
</LinearLayout>
```

In this way your root `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation will have two child i.e the `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation and the `Button`.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: No I can't do that because I also have a button which is add to cart

Comment: Where is the button?

Comment: I have updated my code with the button code please have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
la.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

to this

```
la.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Though, I don't know if it's necessary to build your UI programmatically, but you can easily/better implement that title-subtitle textview using a layout XML, where you can get a preview of what your UI looks like.